# Row of images appearing as column

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm just getting started with tailwind and I would like to grid essentially a row of images that fit the container.
Currently I am just stubbing in 2 photos for testing/getting to know tailwind purposes.

```
<main class="mt-12 lg:mt-32">
    <section class="container mx-auto px-6">
        <div class="w-full lg:flex items-center">
            <div *ngFor="let item of photos">
                <p class="text-md lg:text-xl font-light text-gray-800 mb-8">
                    {{item.description}}
                </p>
                <div class="grid grid-col-2 gap-2">
                    <img [src]="image" *ngFor="let image of item.images"
                        class="object-contain shadow rounded border-none">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

This code is causing the 2 images to essentially appear underneath each other as seen here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGMCV.png

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You have a typo, `grid-col-2` doesn't exist it's `grid-cols-2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should me `grid-cols-2` and the img tag should have `col-span-1`. Checkout [Grid Columns](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-column#class-reference)

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2">  // grid-cols-2
    <img [src]="image" *ngFor="let image of item.images" class="col-span-1 object-contain shadow rounded border-none">  // col-span-1
</div>
```